# Retrofit chaining observables

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, observable, rx-java

I'm trying to use retrofit with rxjava. I have a problem chaining retrofit observables with one another or with observables created by me. Some example:

```
    Observable<List<Friend>> friendsListObservable = friendsService.getFriends();
    Observable<Void> updateReqestObservable = friendsListObservable.switchMap(friends -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Hello");
        return userAPI.updateFriends(session.getUserId(), friends);
    }).subscribe();
```

Everything gets called until it gets to switchMap. So hello is never displayed, but if I return for instance `Observable.just(null)` instead of the retrofit observable it works fine. Also if I user the retrofit observable without chaining, it works.

**Edit1:**
It's an android app. Seems like the map operator is not called at all. Sometimes it happens that with retrofit observables also. I still think that it has something to do with threading. From what I understand an operator is called when an item is emitted, but calling `onNext` doesn't trigger the `map` operator. Below is my whole code:

```
public Observable<List<FacebookFriend>> getFriends() {
    PublishSubject<List<FacebookFriend>> friendsPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    Observable<List<FacebookFriend>> returnObservable = friendsPublishSubject.doOnSubscribe(() -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnSubscribe called");
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        new Request(session, "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                        try {
                            JSONArray friends = graphResponse.getJSONArray("data");
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FacebookFriend>>() {
                            }.getType();
                            List<FacebookFriend> friendsList = gson.fromJson(friends.toString(), listType);

                            friendsPublishSubject.onNext(friendsList);
                            friendsPublishSubject.onCompleted();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            friendsPublishSubject.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
    } else {
        InvalidSessionException exception = new InvalidSessionException("Your facebook session expired");
        friendsPublishSubject.onError(exception);
    }
    });

    return returnObservable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

public Observable<Void> updateFriendsList() {
    Observable<List<FacebookFriend>> facebookFriendsListObservable = facebookService.getFriends();

    Observable<Void> updateReqestObservable = facebookFriendsListObservable.map(friends -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "This is never called");
});
```

}

Comment: Have you try with flatMap or concatMap instead of switchMap ? I don't think the problem is the switchMap, but as I don't know well this operator...

Comment: I tried, no operator gets called, it remains stuck. `onError` doesn't get called either. The only way that works is if I subscribe directly to the observable. I think it might have something to do with threading, but I'm not sure. I ended up using `observable.toBlocking()`. I know this is not good practice but for now we'll do, if someone stumble into the same issue and finds an answer don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: hum, yeah, you're right.
In fact, your call is made asynchronously, and your main method will stop before you get the result. So you'll have to block your main method. So toBlocking is a good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could get around blocking at the actual calling point would be to subscribe it to a subject and then block on the subject at the end of whatever part of your code requires the requests to have been executed.

For example:

```
final ReplaySubject<Void> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
friendsService.getFriends()
    .switchMap(friends -> userApi.updateFriends(session.getUserId(), friends))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(subject);

// Do other things that don't require this to be done yet...

// Wherever you need to wait for the request to happen:
subject.toBlocking().singleOrDefault(null);
```

Since a subject is also an `Observable`, you could even return the subject from a method, and block on it later.

All that being said, it does seem a bit odd to be using the update call as a side effect there. Is `updateFriends` also a Retrofit service? If so, you may want to consider making the update call a synchronous service that returns `void` instead of an `Observable<Void>` that you will call from within an onNext call. If it still needs to block, you can use `forEach` like this:

```
friendsService.getFriends()
    .forEach(friends -> { userApi.updateFriends(session.getUserId(), friends) });
```

`forEach` is very similar to `subscribe`, except that it explicitly blocks. You could even use it with your original code, but added an empty `onNext` action wouldn't be terribly clean.

If you can also provide more details about your app structure (is this all in a main method? is it an Android app? etc.) I could give some more pointers on avoiding blocking as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I updated my post with the whole code. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something terribly wrong. If you have an example on how could I wrap in rx something like Facebook SDK it would be very useful.